# Import from http header options and request deprecated on angular

Tags: angular, http-headers, rxjs, angular-http, angular-httpclient

I need to use the following code that I took from the Internet but I think that it is quite old and it says that the http import is deprecated, how can I fix this ?
It gives me error in all of the http imports and if I change to @angular/comon/http i dont know how to change the hhtp headers and request in the register method .

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

import { UserRegistration } from '../models/user.registration.interface';
import { ConfigService } from '../utils/config.service';

import {BaseService} from "./base.service";

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/Rx'; 

// Add the RxJS Observable operators we need in this app.
import '../../rxjs-operators';

@Injectable()

export class UserService extends BaseService {

  baseUrl: string = '';

  // Observable navItem source
  private _authNavStatusSource = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  // Observable navItem stream
  authNavStatus$ = this._authNavStatusSource.asObservable();

  private loggedIn = false;

  constructor(private http: Http, private configService: ConfigService) {
    super();
    this.loggedIn = !!localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
    // ?? not sure if this the best way to broadcast the status but seems to resolve issue on page refresh where auth status is lost in
    // header component resulting in authed user nav links disappearing despite the fact user is still logged in
    this._authNavStatusSource.next(this.loggedIn);
    this.baseUrl = configService.getApiURI();
  }

    register(email: string, password: string, firstName: string, lastName: string,location: string): Observable<UserRegistration> {
    let body = JSON.stringify({ email, password, firstName, lastName,location });
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + "/accounts", body, options)
      .map(res => true)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }  

   login(userName, password) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this.http
      .post(
      this.baseUrl + '/auth/login',
      JSON.stringify({ userName, password }),{ headers }
      )
      .map(res => res.json())
      .map(res => {
        localStorage.setItem('auth_token', res.auth_token);
        this.loggedIn = true;
        this._authNavStatusSource.next(true);
        return true;
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('auth_token');
    this.loggedIn = false;
    this._authNavStatusSource.next(false);
  }

  isLoggedIn() {
    return this.loggedIn;
  }

  facebookLogin(accessToken:string) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let body = JSON.stringify({ accessToken });  
    return this.http
      .post(
      this.baseUrl + '/externalauth/facebook', body, { headers })
      .map(res => res.json())
      .map(res => {
        localStorage.setItem('auth_token', res.auth_token);
        this.loggedIn = true;
        this._authNavStatusSource.next(true);
        return true;
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Angular 4+, Try:

`import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';`

`constructor(private http: HttpClient)`

`let headers = new HttpHeaders ({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });`

`private options = {        headers: this.headers    };`

Comment: and what i need to change here ? 
`register(email: string, password: string, firstName: string, lastName: string,location: string): Observable<UserRegistration> {
    let body = JSON.stringify({ email, password, firstName, lastName,location });
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + "/accounts", body, options)
      .map(res => true)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }`

Comment: change constructor, header and options code as my posted

Answer (score 0):

From `Angular 4.3` a new `Http Client` was implemented that is more powerful.

**How to use it:**

**STEP 1:** `import` it in your `@ngModule`:
`import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';`

**STEP 2:** Import it in your `imports`:
`@NgModule({ imports: [HttpClientModule] })`

**STEP 3:** Go to your service that handles http operations and import the HttpClient and HttpHeaders:
`import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';`

**STEP 4:** Inject `HttpClient` in your service `constructor`: `constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient)`;

```js
register(email: string, password: string, firstName: string, lastName: string,location: string): Observable<UserRegistration> { 

  let body = JSON.stringify({ email, password, firstName, lastName,location });
  let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); 
  let options = { headers: headers }; 
  return this.httpClient.post(this.baseUrl + "/accounts", body,      
                                  options).pipe(map(res => true));
}
```

Don't forget to import `map` from `rxjs/operators`.